# Calculating remainder of two doubles in java

Tags: java, double

I have the following code :

```
Double x = 17.0;
Double y = 0.1;

double remainder = x.doubleValue() % y.doubleValue();
```

When I run this I get remainder = 0.09999999999999906

Any idea why??

I basically need to check that x is fully divisible by y. Can you suggest alternative ways to do that in java.

Thanks

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is only an approximation of real number arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: That's accurate down to 14 significant digits. What more do you expect from double, which has about this much accuracy?

Comment: `Double y = 0.1;` gives you a double `y` that doesn't exactly represent `0.1`, because it can't be represented as a fraction with a power-of-2 denominator.  (That's how binary floating-point works.)  It's that value you're checking divisibility against, not an exact 0.1

Answer (score 12):

Because of how floating-point numbers are represented.

If you want exact values, use `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal remainder = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).remainder(BigDecimal.valueOf(y));
```

Another way to to that is to multiple each value by 10 (or 100, 1000), cast to `int`, and then use `%`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to compare your result which allows for rounding error.

```
if (remainder < ERROR || remainder > 0.1 - ERROR)
```

Also, don't use Double when you mean to use `double`

Comment: This is the correct answer to use when your data really does come from float/double sources (and is not just discrete data masquerading as floating-point values), and you want to know whether `x` is "very close" to an exact multiple of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Expecting precise results from double arithmetic is problematic on computers. The basic culprit is that us humans use base 10 mostly, whereas computers normally store numbers in base 2. There are conversion problems between the two.

This code will do what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(17.0);
    BigDecimal y = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1);

    BigDecimal remainder = x.remainder(y);
    System.out.println("remainder = " + remainder);

    final boolean divisible = remainder.equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0));
    System.out.println("divisible = " + divisible);

}
```

Comment: Just a complement: you can use `BigDecimal.ZERO` instead of `valueOf(0.0)` for readability. If possible, better use the `new BigDecimal(String)` constructor since `valueOf(double)` still is exposed to precision/rounding errors.